# Firefox float div causes table to float outsite its container

Tags: css, firefox, containers

I have one floating header div set to 1000px inside another div (width 1000px) and followed by a div with a smaller width. The problem is this table inside this div is on the left of the header.
If I add some character above the table, it is ok. Is this a bug?
This works fine in IE and Google Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style>
        #container
        {
            margin: 0px auto;
            width: 1000px;
        }
        #header
        {
            margin-top: 15px;
            width: 1000px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            aaa
        </div>
        <div style="width: 900px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        the wow
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. If what you want is to display the table below the header, simply take out the

> float: left;

Please make clear what you want.